# stop openLayers styling from rendering all (old and new) points by new styling

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a openLayers map and I have different GeoJSON files that I want to be rendered in different Style.
the first I render points it's ok but the second time openLayers re render the old points by new style but I don't want that I want to see only new point whit new Style

how can I solve that ??

```
switch (con) {
  case "tf":
    backTextColor = "#FF7000";
    frontTextColor = "#fff";
    iconText = "T";
    break;
  case "fuse":
    backTextColor = "red";
    frontTextColor = "#fff";
    iconText = "C";
    break;

  case "sec":
    backTextColor = "blue";
    frontTextColor = "#fff";
    iconText = "S";
    break ;

  case "des":
    backTextColor = "green";
    frontTextColor = "#fff";
    iconText = "D";
    break ;

    case "rec":
      backTextColor = "yellow";
      frontTextColor = "#000";
      iconText = "R";
      break ;

}




// *********** TextStyle

const labelText = new Style({
  text: new Text({
    font: '14px Calibri,sans-serif',
    overflow: true,
    fill: new Fill({
      color: frontTextColor
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: backTextColor,
      width: 3
    })
  })
});


const TextPoint = new Style({
  image: new Circle({
    radius: 6,
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: frontTextColor
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
      color: backTextColor
    })

  })
});

labelText.getText().setText(iconText);

const TextStyle = [
  TextPoint,
  labelText
];



// *********** TextStyle


function styleFunc(feature) {
  const style = feature.getGeometry().getType();
  console.log(style);

  if (style === 'LineString') {
    return defaultStyle;
  } else if (style === 'Point') {
    return TextStyle;
  }

}



CreateGeojson("myjson.json")

function CreateGeojson(url) {
  console.log(`url : ${url}`);
  const myGeoJson = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
      format: new GeoJSON(),
      url: url
    }),
    style: styleFunc,
  });
  map.addLayer(myGeoJson);
}
```

the first I render points it's ok but the second time openLayers re render the old points by new style but I don't want that I want to see only new point whit new Style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You got two options**

- set the style dynamically inside the style function
- render the points on different layers, so they have separate style functions

**Here's how to set style dynamically inside style function**

You can add info on the feature properties to distinguish between them when setting the style inside the style function.

```js
oldFeature.set("propName", "oldFeature")
newFeature.set("propName", "newFeature")
```

You can access this custom prop inside the style function

```js
function styleFunc(feature) {
  const propName = feature.get("propName");
  
  if (propName === "oldFeature") {
    // return "old" style
  }
  
  if (propName === "newFeature") {
    // return "new" style
  }
  
  // return some default style?
}
```